# Segmentation fault two dimensional array

Tags: c++

i am new to programing and i am trying to understand the two dimensional array. i wrote this code to just test my code to see if it working or not. unfortunately, i am getting a segmentation error. i know that means that something i wrote is unreadable for the compiler but i do not know what is it. because everything seems fine to me.

```
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;


int main(){

   int col, row,i;
   int **array;

   cout << "How many rows?\n";
   cin >> row;
   cout << "How many colomns\n";
   cin >> col;

cout << "!!!!!!!!!!!!";

   array = new int*[row];
   for (int i = 0;i<row;i++){
          array[i] = new int[col];
   }   

        cout << "!!!!!!!!!!!!";

   for( i=0; i<row; i++){
        int x=1;
      array[0][i]= x;; 
   x++;
   }   
        cout << "!!!!!!!!!!!!";
   cout << array[row][col];

   for(i=0; i<row; i++){

   delete [] array[i];
   delete [] array;
   }   
   return 0; 
}
```

the ERROR is: 
"
How many rows?
3
How many colomns
3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
"

Comment: `cout << array[row][col];` is out of range. `array[row-1][col-1]` is as deep as you can go.

Comment: x++; is not doing anything; x goes out of scope at the end of each loop iteration and is recreated at the start of the next iteration.

Comment: We don't use pointers and arrays and new and deete in C++ much these days. There are healthier alternatives like std::vector and std::shared_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

`array[0][i]= x;` looks wrong. It should be:

```
array[i][0]= x;
```

First index is for row and second for col.

Later `cout << array[row][col];` is also wring as `row` is out of range.

The way you delete the array is also wrong, it should be:

```
for(i=row - 1; i >= 0; --i){
  delete [] array[i];
}
delete [] array;
```

Comment: so it should be like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << array[row][col];
```

Out of range in each of the two dimensions, as others have said.

```
for(i=0; i<row; i++){

delete [] array[i];
delete [] array;
}
```

You're deleting array's elements three times, once for each element.  This is good.  You're also deleting array itself three times.  This is dangerous and wrong.

Answer (score 0):

so it should be like this?

```
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;


int main(){

   int col, row,i;
   int **array;

   cout << "How many rows?\n";
   cin >> row;
   cout << "How many colomns\n";
   cin >> col;

   array = new int*[row];
   for (int i = 0;i<row;i++){
          array[i] = new int[col];
   }   

        cout << "!!!!!!!!!!!!";

   for( i=0; i<row; i++){
        int x=1;
      array[i][0]= x;; 
   x++;
   }   
        cout << "!!!!!!!!!!!!";
   for(i=0; i<row; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<col; j++){
           array[i][j];
        }   
   }   
    cout << array[row][col];    

   for(i=0; i<row; i++){

   delete [] array[i];
   delete [] array;
   }   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: x++; and array[i][j]; do nothing, but they will also harm nothing.  delete[] array; is still incorrectly running three times (assuming row is 3).  Otherwise I see no problems, though I haven't confirmed that by running the code.

Answer (score 0):

This line is out of range `cout << array[row][col];`.If you want to print the last element then change this line to `cout << array[row-1][col-1];`

As others mentioned the below is code for deleting the allocated memory

```
for(i=0; i <row; i++){
    delete [] array[i];       
}
delete [] array;
```

Also in your code below `x` is always going to be `1` , `x++` is noneffective.

```
for( i=0; i<row; i++){
 int x=1;      
 array[0][i]= x; 
 x++;
}
```

if you want to increment `x` for each row then initialize `x` outside the loop
like this

```
int x=1; 
for( i=0; i<row; i++){     
  array[0][i]= x;; 
  x++;
}
```